AspectJ point cut for static method with generic param?
I have two methods I'm trying to capture:
public static <T> HashSet<T> newHashSet() {
public static <T> HashSet<T> newHashSet(Collection<? extends T> c) {

The first one works with:
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.CollectionHelper.newHashSet())")

The second one works with:
  @Pointcut("execution(public * org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.CollectionHelper.newHashSet(..))")

But that's capturing some other overloads that I don't care about. I.e. int. I tried:
  @Pointcut("execution(public * org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.CollectionHelper.newHashSet(Collection))")

But that didn't work.

Did you tried FQN for Collection?

@talex oh shoot haha. Good catch. That's what I get for staring at AspectJ for 2 days now :). Thanks!

@talex, you could write an answer which could then be accepted by the OP. This way, the question would be marked as answered and you would get your well deserved recognition (i.e. reputation points).

@kriegaex I voted to close as misspelling, but if you insist. I love internet points :)

I am not insisting, I was suggesting in a friendly manner. Besides, IMO it is far from a typo not to use a FQN, but a typical user error. Your answer will help others. Because in some circumstances (identical package names) a FQN is unnecessary, it is worth noting this particular problem, and it does not hurt that I have answered similar questions before.

@kriegaex fair enough. Already added my answer. If you have suggestions on improvement I have some time for fixes.

Unfortunately AspectJ don't see your imports, so you have to use FQN for all classes.
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.CollectionHelper.newHashSet(java.util.Collection))")

